# use shell find inside makefile for globs

Tags: shell, makefile

I just can't figure out how to get this desired behavior inside a Makefile:

1) use find to expand a glob search into `/path/match/1`, `/path/match/2`, etc..

2) set that path to a Make variable

Perhaps someone can read my mind and interpret this (incorrect) attempt into a legitimate Make command?

`Makefile
DIRS := $(shell find ./web/{$$(FEATS)}/tests -name "*-spec.js")`

And to execute/consume this makefile, I provide the `FEATS` as an export.

`export FEATS=feature-a,feature-b make run-some-target`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell command that you are executing is

```
find ./web/{$(FEATS)}/tests -name "*-spec.js"
```

I.e. run the shell command `FEATS`, substitute its output into the parameters for `find`, and then run `find`.  To fix, you should only provide one `$`-sign, i.e.

```
DIRS := $(shell find ./web/{$(FEATS)}/tests -name "*-spec.js")
```

What happened is that `make` normally interprets the `$` as the start of a substitution.  But sometimes one needs to pass a literal `$` to commands, and that can be done by preceding the `$` with another `$`.  Make will then collapse that to a single `$`.

Also, when you invoke make, you are using `export`.  Export does not work that way, you probably meant to do one of the following:

```
# note the ';'
export FEATS=feature-a,feature-b; make run-some-target
# or
env FEATS=feature-a,feature-b make run-some-target
# or
FEATS=feature-a,feature-b make run-some-target
# or
make FEATS=feature-a,feature-b run-some-target
```

Comment: Right. Expanding a make variable is either `$(VAR)` or `${VAR}`. Expanding a shell variable inside a make recipe/`$(shell)` command is `$$var` or `$${var}`.

Comment: Ah yes, I meant to have an && between the export and make. However, with this removal of a $ I'm getting `find : './web/{some-feature}/tests': No such file or directory` with an `export FEATS=some-feature` and there is actually a ./web/some-feature/tests directory?

Comment: @Clever There must be at least 1 comma inside braces for the shell to do brace expansion, so `{a}` stays `{a}` whereas `{a,b}` becomes `a` and `b`.

Comment: @meuh I figured as much - and that stinks. That means a whole logic tree to parse `if FEATS is multiple files, use {} else` etc...

Comment: If you can make `FEATS` a space-separated instead of comma-separated list you can pass multiple arguments to  find: `DIRS := $(shell find $(patsubst %,./web/%/tests,$(FEATS)) -name "*-spec.js")`

Comment: Although then `FEATS` should better not be empty, otherwise find will search the current directory.

Answer (score 3):

ex-bart's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32209071/5008284) is the correct one, 
but when you dont need a find but just a glob expansion (eg: `web/*/tests/*-spec.js`)
you may be interested in the built-in `$(wildcard)` command.

Sadly, it doesn't handle {a,b} style expansion, only `?` and `*`. But if you
are willing to change your syntax to "a b" instead, you can use the `$(foreach)`
built-in to iterate through them:

```
FEATS='feature-a feature-b' make
```

with a Makfile:

```
DIRS := $(foreach v,$(FEATS),$(wildcard web/$(v)/tests/*-spec.js))
```